# Can I assign a gesture to Mission Control on an older MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, trackpad, multi-touch

I have an older MacBook (2006) that I want to use the four finger swipe to enable mission control. It is not the glass trackpad, but it does have two finger scrolling. Is there any way to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a hot-corner in Mission Control. This replaces the previous Exposé hot-corner.

Answer (score 0):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) lets you assign arbitrary tap/swipe/click gestures to arbitrary commands.

I don't know if it supports your hardware, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think multi touch gestures are supported in 2006 models.

I thought models < 2007 are not Lion compatible? Needs Core 2 Duo, right?

Comment: "Late 2006" models and onwards had Core 2 Duo chips and are able to run Lion.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the one I have chosen: Buy a Magic Trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

You are limited in almost every way when it comes to using gestures in Snow Leopard on your 2006 MacBook.

### Software

You cannot launch Mission control without OSX Lion, if you do indeed have a 2006 MacBook (which I also have) you cannot install OSX Lion, as it requires a Dual core 2 Duo as a minimum processor, the 2006 have the Dual Core Duo processor. This cannot be changed easily and will be almost as expensive as buying an older 2nd hand MacBook with a glass trackpad ([see my question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36453/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-macbook-processor)) and therfore you cannot use gestures in the same way a MacBook running Lion would do.

### Hardware

The older MacBook cannot perform gestures due to the hardware. The non glass trackpad, cannot detect finger positions in relativity to each other, whereas the [glass ones released in 2008](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2008/02/26Apple-Introduces-New-MacBook-and-MacBook-Pro-Models.html) can.

This means that when you are two finger scrolling it detects two fingers moving down the pad, what it cant do is detect 3 fingers swiping accross a screen, or pinching.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that is one of the reasons (along with iCloud) I bought a new Mac.